# Length of string in line (Python)

Tags: python, md5

I'm currently trying to import a .txt file into some proprietary software but appear to continually receive an error. The .txt file is almost 2GB in size and has approximately 56 million lines.

Having spoken to the manufacturers, they have stated that there may be an error in one of the lines. Each line should contain an MD5 hash value (32-characters) and therefore, using Python v2.7, I'm looking to scan process the .txt file to check the length of each line and print the value of the 'offending' line.

Here's what I've tried:-

```
f = open("x.txt")
contents = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in contents:
    if line(len) == 32:
        continue
    else:
        print line
```

Unfortunately I receive an error when I try this code:-

```
File "<pyshell#30>", line 2, in <module>
  if line(len) == 32:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So I tried the below believing I had to convert the 'line' to an integer:-

```
for line in contents:
    if int(line)(len) == 32:
        continue
    else:
        print line
```

but that just brought back an error of:-

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '000000000000000012452154365298BD"
```

As said, what I'm looking to do is read every line of the .txt file and if it isn't a valid MD5 hash value, print the value to screen or even delete the value.

Many thanks

**[edit]** Turns out it was a schoolboy error. Thanks all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your file is 2 GB in size, I would not recommend doing it the way you're doing it, even if you correct `line(len)` to `len(line)`. You're reading the whole file into memory, which is unnecessary and may cause an out-of-memory error if you don't have enough RAM. Here's how I'd do it:

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        # Remember not to count the newline character
        if len(line.strip()) != 32:
            print line_no, line
```

If you want to remove all lines with the wrong character count, the easiest way is to write a new, correct file:

```
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as out:
    with open("x.txt") as f:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
            if len(line.strip()) == 32:
                out.write(line)
            else:
                print "Removing line {0}".format(line_no)
```

After the script has run, check that the new file looks good, then move the old file to a backup dir and rename the new one `x.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of the "print line_no", how could I change this to delete the line? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`line(len)` is wrong, use `len(line)` instead

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're doing it backwards: use `len(line)` instead of `line(len)`.

Comment: oops... unfortunately I'm not very proficient at python, but I'm learning :) thanks.